# Restify : how do I present a prefilled signin form?

Tags: node.js, restify

Here is my flow.

I have a form (html template with js code ) that needs to be prefilled with some user properties and presented on the path /signup

These properties are passed as url params. There is a javascript in the page that will read this url params and then populate the fields.

I use restify.
Is there a way to present the page using restify ? If so how?
So far I have used restify to return data and not html.

Comment: Restify was built for making APIs. It's unusual to use it to serve up entire html pages. I would use something different for that, although @Dondrey Taylor below shows a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do is inject the parameters into your html template using some type of template engine for Node.JS. There are quite a few that you can use:

[Jade](https://github.com/pugjs/pug)

[Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

[Handlebars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/)

Your route would look something like this if you were to use Handlebars to render your HTML page with populated fields using the parameters within the URL.

```
server.get('/signup/:firstname/:lastname', function (req, res, next) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function (err, data) {
        var template = Handlebars.compile("<form><input type='text' value='{{firstname}}'></form>");
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(template({firstname:"Dee", lastname:"Taylor"}));
    });
});
```